# Helpt with Google Analytics Event Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

Okay, so I have a webpage that uses Google Analytics. It works fine for pageviews, but does not record any events. I use the older script ga.js and my event tracking codes look like

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'click', 'navigation click', 'home']);
```

I use it in different ways, like as an onClick action

```
<a href="#home" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'click', 'navigation click', 'home']);">Home</a>
```

or to record scroll depth (along with the waypoint plugin)

```
$('#printdesign').waypoint(function(direction){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'scroll', 'scroll reach', 'printdesign']);
}, { offset: '20%', triggerOnce: true });
```

Absolutely no event has ever been tracked.

The page has been online for just about a day and a half. Might this be the reason, although pageviews are working? Could there be a conflict with another script? Anything else I might be doing wrong?

**Update:** 
No errors in my js console. In Firebug's DOM-tab I can see my click events 'being sent' through _gaq.push(). I installed httpfox and don't see anything.

**Another update:** 
Funny thing: GA has just started to track *some* of the onClick events, but only in Opera it seems. Some onClicks still aren't recognized and scroll events don't work at all.

**Yet another update:**
In Android's standard browser both click and scroll events work fine! Firefox on Android: nothing. I can't believe this is a browser issue...

**Final one:**
Okay guys. I guess some of you just visited the site and I am seeing your clicks and scrolls and whatnot. I have no idea what causes this odd behaviour, but I'm fine with not seeing my events, but everyone else's :D

Comment: Do you see any errors in your js console?

Comment: No, it doesn't give me any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a http analyzer to check and see when you are clicking on the link, that the event is being triggered/fired?

I use HTTPFox - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httpfox/

but there are plenty others.

Comment: Nope, httpfox doesn't show me anything connected to Google Analytics at all (although pageviews are working).

Comment: Bizarre. Can you share the site?

Comment: @eevaa - I'm using HTTP Fox to analyze the requests and I am seeing click and scroll events fire when I click on Home, Web Design, Print Design, Typografie, and Kontakt. The UA Id is the same as the pageview that is getting fired, too. So the events should be showing up in your real-time dashboard, no?

Comment: Actually, they do. This is really odd, but I'm okay with not recording my own events properly as long as it works for the visitors. Thank you so much for your help! :D

Comment: Make sure you're clearing your cookies and clearing your cache. There is a handy plug-in called "Remove Cookies" which makes it easy to clear then - [link]https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/remove-cookies-for-site/[/link] Feel free to mark the question as answered :) Trying to get points so I can help more people out and post pictures. Thanks